# How do you connect disconnected nodes and make them into a tree?

Tags: c, graph, tree

I'm trying to make a program that makes a tree out of **n** nodes, and I want to find the *longest path of the tree*

[image: The tree I'm trying to construct from nodes]

How should I approach this problem?
I have made an array of Binary Search Trees, but I'm lost on how to connect the disconnected nodes, without making an extra node.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct _node{
    int val;
    struct _node* parent;
    struct _node* left;
    struct _node* right;
}TreeNode;

int main(){
    int n, node_val=0, i, j;
    TreeNode* list[100] ={0};
    TreeNode *current, *prev;
    
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            if(list[i]==NULL) 
            {
                list[i] = (TreeNode*) malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
                list[i]->left = list[i]->parent = list[i]->right = NULL;
                scanf("%d", &node_val);
                list[i]->val = node_val;
            }
            
            else{
                scanf("%d", &node_val);
                if(list[i]->val < node_val){
                    list[i]->left = (TreeNode*) malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
                    prev = list[i];
                    list[i] = list[i]->left;
                    list[i]->parent = prev;
                    list[i]->val = node_val;
                }
                else{
                    list[i]->right = (TreeNode*) malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
                    prev = list[i];
                    list[i] = list[i]->right;
                    list[i]->parent = prev;
                    list[i]->val = node_val;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Am I going into the correct way? Or should I be making another more efficient way?

Comment: I only need to merge the trees without making any changes to the order, so if there are inputs of an already specified node, then I would need to directly connect them to the relevant nodes.

Comment: *"longest path"*: how will you be sure that the input really represents a tree, and that there are no cycles in the graph? Also: your data structure seems to be intended for a *binary* tree (with left & right members). There is no guarantee that the input represents a binary tree.

Comment: @trincot ahhh, i understand your idea, should I change my data structure into a graph data structure instead?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest an adjacency list.